Clone of a uups proxy contract is not working
i have a factory contract which is creating clones of an NFT contract.
if the NFT contract is not a proxy everything is ok and cloning works just fine.
but since i need to have a upgradable UUPS NFT contract for any future changes, i want to set the proxy of the NFT contract as the cloning base, but the cloned contract does not work when they clone the proxy contract rather than the implementation.
so since the cloning contracts can only get the cloned contract address once at their creation, i need to clone the proxy, so clones would delegate the transactions to the proxy contract and the proxy contract should delegate that to the implementation so whenever needed i could update the implementation contract address on the proxy, so clones dont need to get updated.
i tried different proxy methods (transparent and UUPS) to see if clones can delegate to the proxy and proxy to the implementation, but its not working.
is there any way to achieve this or any work around for my use case?
this is the code i use to create a clone contract:
using ClonesUpgradeable for address;
function deployClone(
        string calldata _name,
        string calldata _symbol,
        string calldata _baseTokenURI,
        uint256 _maxSupply,
        uint256 _productId,
        address _admin
    ) external whenNotPaused onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {

        address nftClone = mainNFTAddress.clone();
        NodeNFT(nftClone).initialize(_name, _symbol, _baseTokenURI, _maxSupply, _admin);
        clones[_productId] = address(nftClone);
        clonesList.push(address(nftClone));

        emit CloneDeployed(nftClone, _productId);

    }
    

in here when i use implementation as "mainNFTAddress" clones work fine, but if i use the proxy contract as the base, clones wont work. there is no revert or error.
i would really appreciate any pointers.
thank you
